# Create a bootable USB stick for ubuntu (Mac)

Tags: boot, command-line, dual-boot

Not sure if I did it right, and the file got changed to a .img.dmg  ... not sure how that works. And not sure how long the `sudo dd command` should take?

Answer (score 1):

Using Mac to make bootable USB.

Turn the ISO to an IMG; You first need to rename that and remove the '.dmg' part. It will ask you if you're sure you want to change the file extension;  click yes.

Then you can perform the

```
sudo dd if=Dev/sdx of /path/to/.img
```

Edit: As for how long it takes, it's usually between 5 and 15minutes for my MacBook Air to produce an Ubuntu usb